How can I play music from my iPhone to my Ubuntu desktop?
I own an iPhone XR and I've already ripped my entire collection of old classic CDs into iTunes LOCALLY ONLY on Windoze.  (I don't feel like putting any of this stuff in Apple's cloud.)  Also I've copied all of those albums & tracks into the iPhone XR.  Now what I'd like to be able to do would be to tap, tap,tap on my iPhone to select a song to play and then have the music streamed then & there via Bluetooth (5.0) to my desktop Ubuntu system and then come out my desktop speakers.  Note that I specifically DO NOT want to copy all of my MP3 ripped tracks to my Ubuntu desktop hard drive.  Also, while this is all happening, I still want to be able to do ordinary other stuff on my Ubuntu desktop.
So, what do I need in the way of hardware & software to accomplish the above?  I clearly need a Bluetooth 5 adapter for my desktop system, and the Edimax BT-8500 looks like a good choice for that.  But I still need to know what would be a good software package that will (a) receive streaming audio via Bluetooth and also (b) play that stream out my desktop speakers in real time.
Any suggestions for either hardware or software or both appreciated.

This question is similar to: Can I use my computer as an A2DP receiver / bluetooth speaker?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Yes, that other thread seems to provide a very complete & detailed answer to my exact question, so thanks very much.  (My apologies for not finding that other thread before posting.  I did try.  I just didn't succeed.)

Just one small detail:  I guess that I need to ask the manufacturer if the Edimax BT-8500 supports A2DP under Linux/Ubuntu.  I'm a gonna do that now.

I read that "most modern Bluetooth audio equipment supports A2DP". No guarantees, though...

I asked Edimax the question about A2DP, via email, and they responded quite quickly & on point, so I want to give them a shout out for A+ good customer service.  Anyway, they said yea, their BT-8500 supports A2DP "out of the box" as long as you're running kernel 5.8 or better.  That forced me to finally get off my keister & upgrade from the blgly stale 20.x.x Ubuntu that I was running to 22.x.x which I'm running now.  (Yea yea, I'll get to 24.x.x soon.  Don't bug me!)  So now I get to see if this bluetooth stuff will actually do what I want.

(Yea yea, I'll get to 24.x.x soon.  Don't bug me!)  So now I get to see if this bluetooth stuff will actually do what I want.  So far all I've successfully done is to pair my iPhone XR with the BT-8500 and my Ubuntu desktop system.  Now I gotta go and re-read all that other stuff over in that other thread and see if I can actually make the music go.  The Adventure Begins!  Wish me luck.

Well, son of a gun!  After a modest bit of fiddling & conf file editing, it all works.  I'm sitting here listening to my desktop system's speakers playing a song that I selected on my iPhone.  NICE!  And the up/down volume controls on the iPhone even work while all this is going on.  NICE NICE!
